¿Cómo puedo representar varios dataframes en una misma gráfica en python?
En el ejercicio que estoy intento hacer me pide lo siguiente: "Crea un programa que visualice los casos de coronavirus confirmados en el mundo durante el primer trimestre de 2021 y muéstralo en un gráfico, que incluya un título"
Me facilitan tres archivos excel con los datos de enero, febrero y marzo. He extraído el número de confirmados de cada mes pero no sé cómo representarlos en un gráfico con el eje X siendo los meses y el eje Y los datos de confirmados del trimestre. Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico de líneas (no sé si sería mejor uno de barras) pero por un lado no sé qué hacer con los meses (he intentado meterlo como un array o una lista) y por otro en el argumento "data" al tener tres dataframes no sé si da error.
Necesitaría poder tener en el eje X enero, febrero y marzo y en el eje y los datos de confirmados.



import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df_1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business 
intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-01-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_2 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business 
intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-02-2021.csv", sep = ",")
df_3 = pd.read_csv("/Users/Alvaro/Desktop/Ejercicios Master Big Data y business 
intelligence/Documentos tema python/Trabajo final parte 2/COVID_01-03-2021.csv", sep = ",")

df_total_1= df_1["Confirmed"].sum() 
df_total_2= df_2["Confirmed"].sum()
df_total_3= df_3["Confirmed"].sum()

meses = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

sns.lineplot (x = meses, y = [df_total_1, df_total_2, df_total_3], data = [df_1, df_2, 
df_3], color = ["blue", "red", "green"] ).set_title("Casos confirmados coronavirus 
primer trimestre 2021")

plt.show ()


El primer problema es que tienes datos de tres meses, pero quieres mostrar los 12 meses en el eje X. Como norma general, los iterables con los valores para el eje X y para el eje Y tienen que tener el mismo número de elementos. A cada valor en x le corresponde uno en y.
Otro error es que el argumentocolor en el caso de sns.lineplot permite definir el color a usar para una línea. Si quieres especificar los colores para varias líneas, el argumento a usar es palette junto a hue.
De cualquier forma:

Te piden mostrar los casos confirmados durante el primer trimestre, por lo que bastaría con mostrar estos meses.

Si vas a graficar el total de casos confirmados en el mundo (y no el total por país, por ejemplo), lo que tendrás serán tres valores escalares con el total de casos en cada mes, no tres dataframes. No tiene sentido que uses tres líneas (en realidad serían tres puntos...) si no mostrar los tres datos usando una sola línea, permitiendo ver la evolución.



import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Tres DataFrames solo para hacer reproducible el ejemplo
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"Confirmed": [200, 100, 30, 14, 18]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"Confirmed": [175, 90, 27, 17, 41]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({"Confirmed": [185, 85, 31, 18, 10]})

df_total_1= df_1["Confirmed"].sum()
df_total_2= df_2["Confirmed"].sum()
df_total_3= df_3["Confirmed"].sum()

sns.lineplot (
    x=["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"],
    y=[df_total_1, df_total_2, df_total_3],
    color="red"
).set_title("Casos confirmados coronavirus primer trimestre 2021")

plt.show ()


Si quieres un gráfico de barras sería igual:
meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"]
sns.barplot (
    x=meses,
    y=[df_total_1, df_total_2, df_total_3],
    hue=meses,
    palette=["red", "blue", "green"]
).set_title("Casos confirmados coronavirus primer trimestre 2021")

Aquí puedes ver como se usa palette/hue para dar un color distinto a cada barra (si es que tiene algún sentido):


Buenos días @FJSevilla , muchísimas gracias por la explicación. Como siempre de diez. Me ayudas muchísimo. Un saludo! :D
